# Why are "no-break space" and others ispunct() in GLibC?

Tags: c, unicode, glibc

I've been looking at the `<wctype.h>` flags given to various separator characters by GNU LibC. There are two groups, basically.

The first group returns true on `iswspace()` and `iswblank()` (and `isprint()`, but that is true for the other group as well). These include:

- [U+0020 SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm)
- [U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1680/index.htm)
- [U+2000 EN QUAD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2000/index.htm)
- [U+2001 EM QUAD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2001/index.htm)
- [U+2002 EN SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2002/index.htm)
- [U+2003 EM SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2003/index.htm)
- [U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2004/index.htm)
- [U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2005/index.htm)
- [U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2006/index.htm)
- [U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2008/index.htm)
- [U+2009 THIN SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2009/index.htm)
- [U+200a HAIR SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200a/index.htm)
- [U+205f MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/205f/index.htm)
- [U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm)

No complaints so far. The **other** group has me puzzled, though:

- [U+00a0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)
- [U+2007 FIGURE SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm)
- [U+202f NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm)

These return **false** on `iswspace()` and `iswblank()`, but **true** for `iswpunct()` and `iswgraph()`.

**Why are the last three considered punctuation, not whitespace?**

Java agrees with GLibC on this, apparently (see linked pages). [Unicode](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Property_Values) labels both groups as category 'Zs', "Space_Separator"...

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/iswspace has a note about a list of space characters from ISO 30112, last three not listed there.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC35/WG5/docs/30112d10.pdf working draft for that standard, maybe you'll find some clues in there.

Comment: @Mat: That is a very, *very* valuable link you have provided me with, because the underlying problem I am facing is much larger than this question, and ISO 30112 seems to be *exactly* what I have been looking for...

Comment: That document also explains why no-break spaces aren't in the space category: because they shouldn't be used as word separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO/IEC 30112 *Information technology -- Specification methods for cultural conventions* states, emphasis mine:

> **space**
>
> Define characters to be classified as white-space characters, **to find syntactical boundaries**. [...] The class should **not include the NO-BREAK spaces characters** `<U00A0>`, `<U2007>`, `<UFEFF>`, as these characters should not be used for word boundaries.

Comment: Funny enough, though, that particular standard defines its LC_CTYPE *in terms of glibc output*, so there is a certain bit of circular reasoning involved...